# How can I turn an image into a link to its own source?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<img ex:if-exists=".image" ex:src-content=".image" width="150">
```

How can I turn this image in a link to its own source?

Comment: What do you mean, turn an image in a link to its own source? Please clarify

Comment: what language? what platform client side? server side?  Extremely unhelpful here...

Comment: I'm using this code in a html file to determine how I see a bubble in a Simile Widget Timeline. But this code is connected to this http://api.simile-widgets.org/exhibit/3.1.0rc/extensions/time/time-extension.js. And the ".image" comes from a column in a google spreadsheet and is a url.

Comment: @OliverWilliams  Client side.

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla HTML, you could wrap it in an anchor tag (assuming your image url is `.image`):

```
<a href=".image">
    <img ex:if-exists=".image" ex:src-content=".image" width="150">
</a>
```

Comment: I've tried this before, now again, and it didn't work. But I'm thankful to you for trying to help me :)

Comment: <div ex:role="lens">
         <b ex:content=".label"></b>
         <p ex:content=".start" ex:formats="date { mode: medium; show: date }"></p>
         <p><a href=".image"><img ex:if-exists=".image" ex:src-content=".image" width="150"></a></p>
         <p ex:content=".description"></p>
         <div ex:if-exists=".eventType">Categoria: <span ex:content=".eventType"></span></div>
         <div ex:if-exists=".location">Local: <span ex:content=".location"></span></div>
      </div>

Comment: Can you see the code as I posted it on the comment? @winhowes

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ex:if-exists=".image" ex:href-content=".image" target="_blank">
<img ex:if-exists=".image" ex:src-content=".image" width="150"></a>
```

I found the answer at [Simile widget documentation](http://simile-widgets.org/wiki/How_to_create_dynamic_URLs_using_ex:*-subcontent)

Thank you for your help @winhowes @MCMastery and @OliverWilliams!